# Injecting similar dependency types for different strategies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I currently have code laid out which looks like this:

```
interface strategy {}

interface repository {}

class typeOneStrategy implements strategy {

    List<repository> repositoryList;
}

class typeTwoStrategy implements strategy {
    List<repository> repositoryList;
}

class typeOneRepository implements repository {}
class typeTwoRepository implements repository {}
```

and so on.

I'd like to use Spring's autowiring to inject `typeOneRepository` into `typeOneStrategy` but `typeTwoRepository` should not be injected and instead only be injected for `typeTwoStrategy`.

Is this possible to achieve with Spring's DI?

Comment: Actually, within each `@Configuration`, you can define properties which are `@Autowired` and have `@Qualifier`.

By using these, you can build named beans to define inputs to strategies per the example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, within each `@Configuration`, you can define properties which are `@Autowired` and have `@Qualifier`.

By using these, you can build named beans to define inputs to strategies per the example.

However, I don't consider this to be a very efficient approach?